# PHP page not returning image as expected

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to figure out why the following code will not bring back the results expected. When I click on a link on my main index.php page, it opens a details.php page, on which I have a subpage that would also obtain the information from my URL and then should display images based on that data. However, only if there are more than 1 row in the SQL query.

I can run an SQL query and, if I remove the variables $pid, $lvmID, $in and insert the actual values, results are return. The page WILL show results if there are >= 2 results returned.

My code:

```
<?php
    if (!defined('DB_SERVER')) define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    if (!defined('DB_USER')) define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
    if (!defined('DB_PASSWORD')) define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
    if (!defined('DB_TABLE')) define('DB_TABLE', 'xxx');


    // The procedural way
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['pid']); 
    $lvmID = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['lvmID']); 
    $in = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['in']);

    $query = "
                SELECT r.*, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID
                FROM tbl_random r

                LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
                ON r.img_lvm = lvm.IATAcode

                WHERE r.img_nmr ='$in'
                AND lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID = '$lvmID'
                AND r.randimgID != '$pid'
                LIMIT 6";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: 
    $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    ?>

    <?php
        $items_in_row = 3 ;
        $index = 0 ;
    ?>

        <table width='100%' cellspacing='5' border='0'>
          <tr>

        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
          $index++ ; ?>
          <td style="text-align: center" width='375'>       

             <a href='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/home/details.php?pid=<?php echo $row['randimgID'];?>&lvmID=<?php echo $row['luchtvaartmaatschappijID'];?>&in=<?php echo $row['img_nmr'];?>'> <img src='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/img/random/<?php echo $row['img_lvm'];?>/<?php echo $row['img_file'];?>' width='345'></a> 


            <br>
          </td>
        <?php if ($index%$items_in_row == 0){ ?>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <?php }
        } ?>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) will take one row out from your result set.

Just before closing the connection, you have this call:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Which will actually fetch the first row from your query result. Then, you have your while condition here:

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Which will fetch the **second** row from your results, and then execute the inside of the loop *if there is a second row*. So the first row your query returns will never be processed inside the while loop.

The solution is simply to remove the first call to mysqli_fetch_assoc(), and leave the full code like this:

```
<?php
    if (!defined('DB_SERVER')) define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    if (!defined('DB_USER')) define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
    if (!defined('DB_PASSWORD')) define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
    if (!defined('DB_TABLE')) define('DB_TABLE', 'xxx');


    // The procedural way
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
        trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['pid']); 
    $lvmID = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['lvmID']); 
    $in = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['in']);

    $query = "
                SELECT r.*, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID
                FROM tbl_random r

                LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
                ON r.img_lvm = lvm.IATAcode

                WHERE r.img_nmr ='$in'
                AND lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID = '$lvmID'
                AND r.randimgID != '$pid'
                LIMIT 6";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: 
    $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    ?>

    <?php
        $items_in_row = 3 ;
        $index = 0 ;
    ?>

        <table width='100%' cellspacing='5' border='0'>
          <tr>

        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
          $index++ ; ?>
          <td style="text-align: center" width='375'>       

             <a href='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/home/details.php?pid=<?php echo $row['randimgID'];?>&lvmID=<?php echo $row['luchtvaartmaatschappijID'];?>&in=<?php echo $row['img_nmr'];?>'> <img src='http://globe-trekking.com/vg/img/random/<?php echo $row['img_lvm'];?>/<?php echo $row['img_file'];?>' width='345'></a> 


            <br>
          </td>
        <?php if ($index%$items_in_row == 0){ ?>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <?php }
        } ?>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: thanks. that makes perfect sense. I see my error now that you've pointed it out.